# Windows service is disabling Cortana - Windows 10 (ver 1511)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, services, windows-10-v1511

After updating to Windows 10 ver **1511** (build **10586.29**) the following issues arose:

1. There is a two second delay from clicking the start menu to it appearing.
2. Search functionality within the start menu I.E Cortana does not open or search.

---

### TESTING

After removing all startup items and services I managed to find the service that was causing the issue.

***Network Location Awareness***

- It seems that this service is preventing Cortana from loading correctly.
- When this service is disabled Cortana loads correctly and the start menu  loads immediately.
- Unfortunately this service is needed to display network activity so disabling it is not an option.

  ---

#### TESTING NOTES

1. Explorer searching works fine.
2. Cortana process is not running in task manager when the `Network Location Awareness` service is running.
3. I am connected to a **domain**.
4. Other user on the same domain and build do not experience the issue.
5. I have now done a system reset *(re-installing Windows and removing all existing programs)*. The problem persists.

Any advise on further diagnosing or resolving the issue is appreciated.

Comment: This problem is unique to your system, my Windows 10 system, does experience the same problem.  If you boot into a minimal boot configuration do you still experience the behavior with the start menu?

Comment: No there is no issue in mimimal boot. I tested all start programs and services and found that the service noted above is definately causing the issue, I just dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is specific however anyone who suffers from similar issues may find this information helpful.

If upon diagnosis you find a similar issue with one of your services as above then restting your pc may not fix the issue.

The problem in this case was a corrupted `.dll` which ran the Cortana service.

When resetting your pc via the Windows recovery services within Windows 10, new windows files are **not downloaded**, the resetting process uses existing windows files already on your computer. If these files are corrupt then you wont get the same as a clean install.

My advice would be to **always do a clean install** instead of a reset to ensure you get not only the latest version but a clean one.

**Please Note:** You can still do this even if you have *upgraded* to Windows 10.

As long as you have previously activated Windows you will not need a license key to activate.